# How can I exclude all “permission denied” messages from “find” in Solaris

Tags: grep, find, solaris

Hi previous questions on this topic contain answers for Linux but does not work for Solaris 10.

```
find . ! -readable -prune
```

Does not work in solaris since -readable is not POSIX.

What is the POSIX compliant command that  exclude all “permission denied” messages from “find” in Solaris?

**Correct answers: jlliagre and random832 gave correct answers.**

Comment: You are trying to not to print them?

Comment: Those errors are given on STDERR, a quick and dirty hack would be to redirect STDERR to `/dev/null`  ... `find . -prune 2> /dev/null`. However any other errors will be lost too.

Comment: Sorry your command doesn't work:

find: bad option 2
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list

Comment: @hewei Are you using (t)csh? [Don't use (t)csh.](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt)

Comment: @hewei If you must use csh, the (somewhat, if you want it in a file you need to put the file instead of /dev/tty) equivalent command is `(find . -prune > /dev/tty) >& /dev/null`.

Comment: the above works, thanks, tcsh is default on this SunOS  SPARC-Enterprise.

Comment: @hewei Yeah, it's a bad default.  Install zsh or bash, you will be much happier.

Comment: I agree. Apparently your id -G id -u are not POSIX , do you mind modifying your code and answer my question #2? Thanks

Comment: @hewei I just edited my question.  `id -G` and `-u` *are* POSIX, [see here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/id.html).  It is Solaris's default shell utilities that are stuck in 1994 or something.  The PATH setting *should* correct for this.

Comment: Very much a duplicate of the Stack Overflow question [How can I exclude all permission denied messages from `find`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762348/how-can-i-exclude-all-permission-denied-messages-from-find/)  Note that the currently accepted answer may not work on Solaris unless you're using GNU `find` there.  Other answers will help for Solaris.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a POSIX way to prune any non readable directory with `find` :

```
find . \( -exec sh -c ' if [ ! -r "$1" ] ; then { exit 1 ; } ; else for i in "$1"/* ; do if [ -d "$i" -a ! -r "$i" ]; then exit 1; fi; done; fi ' sh {} \; -o -prune \) -a -print
```

Note that if this is a full Solaris installation, GNU grep is available in `/usr/sfw/bin/ggrep`.

Comment: This does not work: wrds(/)% find .  \( -exec test ! -r {} \; -prune \) -a -print                   find: cannot read dir ./lost+found: Permission denied
find: cannot read dir ./var/lost+found: Permission denied

Comment: `-a -print` should be `-o -print`, I believe.

Comment: I am in ksh , and your first command find . \( -exec sh -c 'if [ ! -r "$1" ] ; then { exit 1 ; } ; fi ' sh {} \; \     -o -prune \) -a -print yields: "
find: cannot read dir ./var/sadm/pkg/SMCvim/save: Permission denied
find: cannot read dir ./var/sadm/pkg/SMCnedit/save: Permission denied
........"

Comment: Indeed, I just modified my answer to fix this, I hope.

Comment: It works indeed, thanks. One downside of ksh is that the arrow keys don't work. For exmaple, uparrow yields ^[[A on Putty

Comment: I believe you can use bash to get the arrow keys working.

Comment: Would you please take a look at my new question, zwol told me I should create a new question rather than asking two questions in this thread, <http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222201/posix-compliant-recursive-grep-with-no-errors-for-inaccessible-directories>

Answer (score 2):

Just filter them out.

```
find . 2>&1 | grep -v "^find: cannot read dir .*: Permission denied$"
```

Comment: I'm sorry it doesn't work on SunOS wrds3 5.10 Generic_150400-23 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise. The results are:

wrds(~)% find . 2>&1 | grep -v "^find: cannot read dir .*: Permission denied$"
Illegal variable name.

Comment: @hewei Use ksh instead of csh for your shell.

Answer (score 0):

If you would prefer not to invoke a subshell for every single file, this refinement of jlliagre's answer does it all with `find` predicates, as long as there are no ACLs to make it even more complicated.  Correctly handling directories that are readable but not searchable is left as an exercise.  If you haven't seen the `#!` thingy before, it means "don't try to copy all this onto the command line; instead, put it in a file, verbatim, `chmod +x` it, and invoke it as `./nameoffile <directory>`."

```
#! /usr/xpg4/bin/sh

PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
export PATH

me="-user $(id -u)"
my_groups="( -group $(id -G | sed 's/ / -o -group /g') )"

prune_me="( ( $me ! -perm -0400 ) -prune )"
prune_group="( ( ! $me $my_groups ! -perm -0040 ) -prune )"
prune_other="( ( ! $me ! $my_groups ! -perm -0004 ) -prune )"

find "$@" $prune_me -o $prune_group -o $prune_other -o -print
```

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work as it says "
wrds(~)% mysearch.sh /
id: illegal option -- u
Usage: id [-ap] [user]
id: illegal option -- G
Usage: id [-ap] [user]
find: cannot find ! name
"   Would you have a script that would allow me to grep a keyword , for example 'Carhart' inside all .sas files in all subdirectories, I tried something like the following but doesn't work: (find . -name '*.sas' -prune -type f -exec grep 'Carhart' > /dev/tty) >& /dev/null

Comment: Try with the two lines I just added.  For the grepping of a keyword, please ask a new question.  We strongly prefer one and only one question per question.

Comment: It no longer shows id error, but it shows "bash-3.2$ find: cannot read dir /var/sadm/pkg/SUNWrda/save: Permission denied
bash: find:: command not found
bash-3.2$ /var/sadm/pkg/SUNWrda/pkginfo
bash: /var/sadm/pkg/SUNWrda/pkginfo: Permission denied
bash-3.2$ /var/sadm/pkg/SMCiperf
bash: /var/sadm/pkg/SMCiperf: is a directory
.........."

Comment: I need to see the output of `ls -l /var/sadm/pkg/SUNWrda` please.  Edit it into your question - don't put it in the comments here.

Comment: @hewei OK: my answer should have worked on that.  I cannot help you any further.

Comment: no problem . jlliagre and random832 gave correct answers.