# POSIX-compliant recursive grep with no errors for inaccessible directories

Tags: grep, find

What script would allow me to grep a keyword and print the filename containing the keyword inside the file content, for example 'Carhart' inside all .sas files in all subdirectories? I tried something like the following but it doesn't work:

```
(find . -name '*.sas' -prune -type f -exec grep 'Carhart' > /dev/tty) >& /dev/null
```

The script would satisfy two conditions

1. It runs on tcsh on Solaris on SPARC-Enterprise, which is certified POSIX
2. It does not generate 'Permission denied' lines on directories which I have no permission to search and/or read.  ( find / -name '*.sas' -prune > /dev/tty ) > & /dev/null

Since  `( find / -name '*.sas' -prune > /dev/tty ) > & /dev/null` works without reporting permission denied error, how can I modify this simple line to incorporate grep?

Comment: Note that `tcsh` is not and never will be certified to be POSIX compliant. On Solaris, you need to run `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` as your shell and have the POSIX PATH set to `getconf PATH) to comply.

Comment: Why do you need that the errors are not printed?

Comment: Running `truss -a -f -u :: find /var ...` seems to confirm that it works like https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/master/usr/src/cmd/find/find.c#L847 , that is, it calls `nftw` and if `nftw` detects a directory that is not readable, `find` outputs an error message before doing anything else (even before doing  `-type d -a test_for_unreadability -a -prune`) . The best thing to do may be to filter out the error messages on stderr rather than trying to come up with a set of conditions to pass to `find` that will make it avoid unreadable directories.

Comment: Thank you for confirming Gilles' answer won't work. Would you have a solution?

Comment: He's not only saying that Gilles answer will not work, but any answer at all, because find tries to `open()` first. You will have them printed anyways. Is there a reason why you don't want them to be printed?

Comment: @hewei: if you're ok with discarding *all* error messages, you can just redirect stderr to `/dev/null.`  In POSIX sh, you'd use `find ... ` 2> /dev/null`.  Do the tcsh equivalent of that.

Comment: Thank you. is the correct answer?: It seem to direct all output, not just stderr, to null in tcsh `(find / -name '*.sas' -type f -exec grep -F -l 'Carhart' {} + >/dev/tty ) > & /dev/null`

Answer (score 4):

To make grep print only the file name, pass the `-l` option. To search for a substring rather than a regular expression, pass the `-F` option.

To search recursively for files whose name matches a certain pattern, use `find` with the `-type f` and `-name PATTERN` primaries. Use `-exec` to invoke grep.

```
find . -name '*.sas' -type f -exec grep -F -l 'Carhart' {} +
```

If you want to avoid errors from directories that you aren't allowed to traverse, you can either use `-perm`, `-user` and `-group` to analyze permissions (which is difficult to get right, and won't work if you have ACL), or call `test` (which is slowed because it's an external program, but is more reliable).

```
find . -type d ! -exec test -r {} -a -x {} \; -prune -o \
       -name '*.sas' -type f -exec test -r {} \; -exec grep -F -l 'Carhart' {} +
```

Comment: I'm sorry even your second command would generate errors "find: cannot read dir ./var/sadm/pkg/SUNWdtdmn/save: Permission denied
find: cannot read dir ./var/sadm/pkg/SUNWdthez/save: Permission denied
.... "

Comment: @hewei That would happen only if the permission bits indicate that you can access these directories, but the access actually fails. As far as I know this shouldn't happen for normal filesystems on Solaris (it can happen with “weird” filesystems such as Samba). What filesystem is that directory on?

Comment: @hewei Use backticks for code. Click the “help” button near the “Add Comment” button to see help on formatting code. This script is very complex, I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: That complex script , which I don't understand either, was the answer from jlliagre on <http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222175/how-can-i-exclude-all-permission-denied-messages-from-find-in-solaris>

Comment: @hewei The only effect of `-prune` is to stop descending into directories whose name matches `*.sas`, it doesn't change what's done on other directories or what's done on non-directories matching `*.sas`. So see my first command.

Comment: Solaris find implements `-exec` by using `fork` and `execvp`, that is, it doesn't run a shell. So `-exec ! anything` is always going to be false, because there's no executable in the standard search path named `!`.

Comment: The `/var/sadm/pkg/*/save` directories are root:root, mode 750.

Comment: @hewei Mark Plotnick found an error in the second command. Try the fixed command.

Comment: doesn't work. `grep: illegal option -- F
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .`

Comment: @hewei `-F` is a POSIX option. Do you have `/usr/xpg4/bin` before `/usr/bin` in your PATH? If not, you can remove it, then the pattern will be interpreted as a basic regular expression rather than a string.

Comment: even with an all POSIX 2.0 command : `/usr/xpg4/bin/find / -type d ! -exec /usr/xpg4/bin/test -r {} -a -x {} \; -prune -o \
       -name '*.sas' -type f -exec /usr/xpg4/bin/test -r {} \; -exec /usr/xpg4/bin/grep -F -l 'Carhart' {} +` , it still doesn't achieve the objective of not printing permission denied errors. Something is wrong with your logic behind the code.  `/usr/xpg4/bin/find: cannot read dir /var/sadm/pkg/SUNWcsl/save: Permission denied
/usr/xpg4/bin/find: cannot read dir /var/sadm/pkg/SUNWkvm/save: Permission denied
........`